# Grafana Agent in Docker runs perfectly for over a week and then suddenly stops working. When we check, the Data folder is gone

Tags: docker, prometheus, grafana

We have deployed the Grafana Agent using the official Docker image to send metrics of our server and containers to Grafana Cloud:

```
docker run \
  -v /etc/grafana-wal:/etc/agent/data \
  -v /etc/grafana-agent.yaml:/etc/agent/agent.yaml \
  grafana/agent:latest
```

This works perfectly for many days. We can see that both the **/etc/grafana-wal** folder has information and it matches the contents of the folder inside the container **/etc/agent/data**

The problem arises after approximately 7-12 days, we noticed that metric data stops showing up in Grafana Cloud.

When we check the docker logs we see this error, which shows that somehow the agent can't access the wal directory anymore.

```
error tailing WAL" err="segments: open /etc/agent/data/074c616f5ce774d7471a5621e3dd24b5/wal: no such file or directory
```

So then we go check those mounted folders again and the host folder **/etc/grafana-wal** still has all the data. But when we navigate inside the container the **/etc/agent** folder exists but is empty. there is no **/data** folder inside.

We haven't touched the server during this time, we haven't restarted any container or updated anything.

If we restart the docker container everything goes back to normal.

I also noticed the **/etc/agent/agent.yaml** config file also disappears inside of the container. But when I run an inspect on the container, it still shows like they are mounted.

```
"Mounts": [
        {
            "Type": "bind",
            "Source": "/tmp/agent",
            "Destination": "/etc/agent",
            "Mode": "",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": "rprivate"
        },
        {
            "Type": "bind",
            "Source": "/etc/grafana-agent.yaml",
            "Destination": "/etc/agent/agent.yaml",
            "Mode": "",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": "rprivate"
        }
 ]
```

Any ideas of what could be causing the "data" folder to disappear inside the Grafana agent container?

Comment: `approximately 7-12 days` first thing you need to do is enable auditing. You need to know *when* it occurs. 7-12 isn't a when, it's a store name.

Answer (score 2):

The issue you're facing with the Grafana Agent container losing access to its data directory and configuration file is likely related to a Docker volume management issue.

Volume Prune: Docker has a built-in feature called "volume prune" that removes unused volumes. It's possible that even though your container is referencing the mounted volumes, Docker might be considering them unused after a period of inactivity and removing them during a prune cycle.

Volume Propagation: The rprivate propagation mode you're using for the volumes restricts them to the current container instance. This means if the container restarts, Docker might not automatically recreate the volume mounts.

Docker Storage Driver: The behavior of volumes can also be influenced by the Docker storage driver in use. Some drivers might handle volume persistence differently.

Here's how you can troubleshoot the issue:

Disable Volume Prune:  Check if Docker volume prune is enabled. You can temporarily disable it using the docker volume prune -f command with the -f flag to force removal. This will prevent Docker from removing potentially used volumes. However, this is not a permanent solution, and you should investigate further.

Change Volume Propagation: Try modifying the volume mounts in your docker run command to use the rw propagation mode instead of rprivate. This allows Docker to recreate the volume mounts if the container restarts.

Inspect Docker Storage Driver:  Investigate the storage driver Docker is using. Some drivers like aufs might have limitations on volume persistence. You can check the storage driver using docker info. Refer to the documentation for your specific driver to understand volume behavior.

Consider Persistent Volumes: Instead of relying on bind mounts, explore using Docker volumes with a storage driver that guarantees persistence like local volumes with the `-v /path/on/host:/path/in/container:local` option or named volumes with

```
docker volume create <volume-name>.
```

you may also need to set resource limits for the agents containers running